# Finding shortest length between to regions of interest

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary, distance

I have a binary image with several regions of interest which I have identified via `bwconncomp`. I am trying to find the shortest point connecting each of these regions. I was considering using dilation with larger and larger kernel sizes within a loop with code similar to below, pausing the loop when the number of connected components drops, then maybe identifying those which have connected by sizable changes in centroids and using the number of iterations times two to gives the approximate distance? I feel like there should be a better way of doing this?

```
distancebetweenROIS=[];
M11=tempBimage;

for c=1:50          
    TT=bwconncomp(M11);
    seDil=strel('disk',c);
    M11=imdilate(tempBimage,seDil);
    YY=bwconncomp(M11);
    if length(TT.PixelIdxList)>length(YY.PixelIdxList)
        distancebetweenROIS(end+1)=c*2;
    end

end
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you could do this using [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) if you just pass it each pair of regions (specified as lists of (x,y) coordinates). If you don't have the stats toolbox then try http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29004-feature-points-in-image--keypoint-extraction/content/FPS_in_image/FPS%20in%20image/Help%20Functions/SearchingMatches/pdist2.m

Answer (score 2):

Using `bwdist` and `bwlabel`, you can find the shortest distance of any feature to all other features. All you have to do is then to loop through the features.

```
%// labeledImage is 1 on feature #1, 2 on feature #2, etc

labeledImage = bwlabel(yourBinaryImage);

nLabels = max(labeledImage(:));

%// find the distance between each label and all other labels

distMat = zeros(nLabels, nLabels);

for iLabel = 1:nLabels

%// distance transform - every pixel is the distance to the nearest 
%//   non-zero pixel, i.e. the location of label iLabel

dist = bwdist(labeledImage==iLabel);

%// use accumarray b/c we can
%// get rid of the zeros in labeledImage, though, as there is no index 0

distMat(:,iLabel) = accumarray(dist(labeledImage>0),labeledImage(labeledImage>0),[],@min);

end
```

Note that the distance is equivalent to "how many hops do I need at minimum if I start on feature X and hop from pixel to pixel onto feature Y". If you need the distance between centroids, `regionprops(yourBinaryImage,'Centroids')` followd by `pdist2` is the better approach.

Comment: Once correction: the last line should be like `distMat(:,iLabel) = accumarray(labeledImage(labeledImage>0), dist(labeledImage>0),[],@min);`

Comment: One question though: is it possible to get the equation of the line of the shortest distance?